# React Js PropTypes required without type

Tags: input, reactjs, components

I'm implementing a reusable Input component with React (ES6). I want to make the props "value" generic (like without defining a type).

For now, type is set to string but I don't want that since the Input component must handle number / string / password / etc

```
value: React.PropTypes.string
```

And I need something like

```
value: React.PropTypes,
```

Which is not possible.
Is someone know a elegant solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `requiredAny: React.PropTypes.any` which is a value of any datatype.

Answer (score 2):

While iamsaksham's answer is technically correct, it would probably be a better idea to do something like this:

```
value: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.number
])
```

This will give you much better control, as PropTypes.any doesn't really add much type safety to your code.

(Also, React.PropTypes has been moved to a separate package so you need to do `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';` nowadays)

See [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) for more info.